# Childhood lego car ID, 1980s early 90s

Tags: set-identification, sets

I'm looking to ID 2 sets I had as a kid,

One was a rally car, it was white with a red base, the wheel centres were red. The driver I think was white upper, red or white lower and with a red helmet and white body with stripe from one side to the other of his upper body. I think the car roof had a sun roof, I think the windows and sun roof were blue tint?

The other was a yellow 4wd with a trailer, which I think had a blue motorbike. From memory the 4wd had a black base, the wheels possibly had white centres.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the second set you describe is [6677 Motocross racing](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6677-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) (from 1986):
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Could the first car be the [6634 Stockcar](https://brickset.com/sets/6634-1/Stock-Car)?

[image]

The driver would be [this](https://brickset.com/minifigs/s007/s-white-with-red-black-stripe-white-legs-red-classic-helmet), maybe the other sets he appeared in would help.